# I have just one OS in my laptop, why Have I 3 partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-partition

I am QUITE new in this topcis.
My laptop has only one OS, ubuntu 20.04

When I come to gparted, I saw 3 partitions and one unallocated.

```
1- /dev/sda1 ext4 => I read this should by my OS, (ext4 is for linux right?)
2- /dev/sda2 fat32 => what is that? this should be for dual boot with windows?
3- /dev/sda3 extended => 224.45 gb size --- --- (what is that?)
```

If a open number 3-

```
  unallocated unallocated 1MiB
  /dev/sda5 ext4 => linux again right? (224.45 GiB
  unallocated unallocated
```

I show you a pictured.[image: screenshoot]

I am just wondering, should I delete some partitions to run my linux faster and have more free space to make things work better?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it for now as long as your system works OK. Tinkering around without knowing what you are doing can make matters worse. You have lots of space available for Ubuntu now (90% free our about 175 GB).

Spend a year or two learning more about Linux and Ubuntu and if by that time you need more space you can wipe out `sda5` and reclaim it for Ubuntu. Deleting it now will not make Ubuntu run any faster and could leave you with a bricked system.

Your question is kind of broad: *"Here's a picture of what I have, I don't know what it means what should I do?"*. So far others not familiar with your system are speculating on how your system might be setup.

Over the next year or two try to read up on:

- BIOS (Basic Input Output System)
- CSM / Legacy Boot
- UEFI

In the meantime just use Ubuntu day to day and enjoy it.

Comment: thank you. I have been learning for last year about programming: node js react. It is very difficult to learn about hardware and OS, documentation is explain for people how has high o medium knowlage about it. I will still try to do it

Comment: @titoih I know what you mean. I spent a couple of days learning Gnome Javascript and opted for learning Python instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is installed to `/dev/sda1`.

`/dev/sda2` is a `fat32` partition that could be used for `efi`, but the system is not installed in UEFI mode.

`/dev/sda3` is an extended partition that contains `/dev/sda5`. The latter is not mounted anywhere. It can be used for additional storage, etc.

This is kind a weird installation.

Nothing will work faster if you remove the `/dev/sda5` partition, you can use it.

Comment: could you say some post or documentation to understand EFI, UEFI mode? thanks

Comment: You can use google search and find out lots of info.

Comment: The easiest option would be to do a fresh install. Installer will do  partitioning properly for you.

Comment: I did do a fresh install when I got the laptop, and I have the partition as you see. I used a usb bootable with linux 20.04, maybe I should do it in other way?

Comment: You probably did a manual install and selected a partition manually. But if you choose "Erase all and install" all partitions will be removed and you'll have proably only one partition.

Comment: @Pilot6 How do you know if the OS is installed in UEFI-mode or not? I don't see any evidence for this statement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: This is what you picked at install time. With some existing partitions, you may have selected to use the existing partition structure.

The columns in gparted can give you some more information about what the partitions are used for.

`/dev/sda` is an identifier for a disk. Any number after `/dev/sda` is a partition number.

`/dev/sda1` is filesystem type `ext4` and the mount point is `/`. This indicates that your Linux system is using this partition as the top of the filesystem tree. It is about half your disk at 240 GB.

`/dev/sda2` is filesytem type `fat32`. The part that is interesting about this line is that the flags used are 'boot' and 'esp'. This indicates your system uses this during the boot process, and also that you have an EFI type install (instead of a legacy BIOS install).

`/dev/sda3` is an extended partition, and you'll notice it drops down as a container to include `/dev/sda5/`.

Unallocated space is pretty tiny, and can be part of previous partitioning. Even a fresh partition scheme may require 1MB blocks for alignment. This is tiny, I wouldn't worry about it.

At install time, you may have been presented with some partition options that you agreed to, and perhaps this layout was already present on your disk. I agree this is a bit of a strange layout, and I also agree that deleting any partitions are not going to make your system run any faster. You may need to do something to make full use of your disk.

If you have just installed, you can always install again and have a closer look at the partition options section. You could boot to the installer and see what partition options it presents without proceeding too.

As an example, here is a disk partitioned by the installer using default options on a BIOS system:
[image: Partition of sda Ubuntu 18.04.03 default - BIOS]
Note that it has '/dev/sda1' as the only partition.

Here is a disk partitioned by the installer using defaults for options on an EFI system:
[image: Partition of sda Ubuntu 20.04 default - EFI]

Comment: Actually, this is a laptop that has been before in other hands. That's could explain weird things. I am going to research about EFI and legacy BIOS differences as you commented. I will keep this partition like that until laptop get old and maybe I could reinstall everything. Just last question, is it recommendable to have one or two partitions? Imagine if I reinstall today, what did you advice as perfect partition disk? one, two, three?

Comment: That's entirely a matter of personal preference. Advice for a new user: Stick to the installer defaults. You can always re-partition later.

Comment: Stick to the installer defaults certainly for now. The defaults give one big partition, plus support for booting.